# How to Compare String with Hashtable object in javascript

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to compare the string with Hashtable value. Using hashtable i am storing key and values. Everything is going good but during comparing of hashtable value with String was fail.

```
var name= this.innerText;
var cityName=name.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
for(var k in cityHash ){
    if(cityHash.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        if(cityName.toLowerCase()==cityHash[k].toLowerCase()){
            alert("Match");
        }
```

Comment: You're javascript is missing a few closing brackets. Try adding those and see if there's a difference. If that doesnt work try including an example of the cityHash object and this.innerText.

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: @Syon Looping is perfect in my original code. Actual problem is its not shows the alert("Match");. Dont know why its not comparing the hashtable objects with string. There is anyother special method for comparison ?

Comment: @benzonico Problem is not entering into comparing IF loop and not receiving MATCH alert. In logcat, there is no errors

Comment: Your code works if the object value matches the innerText, see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezXaU/

Comment: @Syon Thanks. Let me check and come back to u

Comment: Thank @Syon I found out solution

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out solution for this problem. I forgot to **Trim** the two Strings, One for value from hashtable and another is Inner text of UL before comparing.